# Automatically obtaining market data from MetaTrader 5 using MatLab

Tags: matlab, api, database-connection, metatrader5

I'm looking for a way to automatically run a script on MatLab which outputs price data from MetaTrader 5. Can anybody provide me a link to someone who has done this before or the best way to go about doing it?

I've researched online and could not find any useful article to deal with this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I've been downloading live Metatrader data, charting it with Matplotlib and developing indicators in Python. There is a user group with links to the code you need to acces the metatrader feed

There's a thread on it here: https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/306742

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for your reply. You don't happen to know a similar thread for MatLab specifically?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to make an interaction between Matlab and Metatrader. The newest way is using Matlab COM services. It can be done either directly or indirectly. The indirect way is possible through the Excel DDE server. I've done it recently using Matlab "actxserver" for the Excel application. The data is first sent from Metatrader to Excel and then read by Matlab through the COM server. Exporting data from MetaTrader to Excel through the DDE server is explained here:
[Export data from MT5 to Excel](https://www.mql5.com/en/code/1246).
Exporting data from Excel to Matlab through COM server is also explained here:
[Export data from Excel to Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94023-how-do-i-read-data-from-an-excel-spreadsheet-using-the-automation-client-support-in-matlab).
These days I'm trying to make a complete direct interaction between MT5 and Matlab. You can contact me for further information if needed.